# VBA for cell that colored by Conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, getcolor

I hope I can get answer here.
It must be a simple question but I am out of option now.

I have a sheet where i used conditional formatting to highlight cells, in another sheet i wanted to get the color of that cell, so I made the VBA function below so I can use a formula to get the color.

This is my VBA function

```
Function GetColouring(FCell As Range)

    GetColouring = FCell.Interior.ColorIndex

End Function
```

And this is my formula in my sheet that supposed to get the color of the cells.
`=@getcolouring(OFFSET(POAP!$I$5,$A20,$B20+($C20-1)*19))`

I use it with Offset formula due to the format of my sheet with conditional formatting.
it is working if the cell are manually colored but returning "White or -4142" only if conditional formatting.  I already tried other suggested code from google `GetColouring = FCell.displayformt.Interior.Color`
but it is only returning #VALUE!.

What is the correct code so I can get the color of cell highlighted by conditional formatting.

Comment: `DisplayFormat` is the property you want but you cannot use it in a UDF called from a sheet.

Comment: Hi Rory, If i cannot use UDF what function should I use?

Comment: Do you really want to write the Color-Index into another cell? What problem do you want to solve with that?

Comment: There isn't a function for it. You can create a UDF for it, but it will be quite complicated depending on the formatting criteria involved. I suspect there are better ways to achieve your end goal, whatever that may be.

Comment: Not an answer: Would you not rather put the formula of the conditional formatting in your UDF and display some real results like "good", "poor", "ok"? Capturing the color is quite around the corner. Plus, the cell does not have the color, it just has the conditional formatting which acts respectively.